# How do I configure my .htaccess file to prepend 'www.' to all of my requests?

Tags: .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.htaccess, forcing a slash and www](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223782/htaccess-forcing-a-slash-and-www)

How do I configure my .htaccess file to prepend 'www.' to all of my requests? I've tried this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule...
```

Comment: This has been asked and answered 10s if not 100s of times on this site.  You might try searching.

Comment: this shoould work... try to remove the first line, it looks unusual to me.

Answer (score 1):

Try to negate `www.example.com` instead of matching `example.com` like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: not a good idea... once you may need to add new subdomain.example.com. Moreover, this is not the core of the problem.