# How to redirect /blog to /blog/?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect /blog to /blog/. I have two condition if blog is in the url first condition will be called else second condition. Please anybody help me to do this.

I did this.

```
#blog
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog.*
RewriteRule (.*)           /blog/$1   [L]

#squeezepage
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ index.php?option=com_squeezepage&sqpage=$1 [NC]
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the problem with that code?

Comment: Its working for everything except giving 500 internal error for blog.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this to redirect `/blog` to `/blog/` however if `/blog` is a physical folder then Apache does it automatically for you:

```
RewriteRule ^blog$ /blog/ [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you only want the trailing slash for /blog requests or do you want it for all directories?
Because there is a directive called `DirectorySlash on` which might be what you're looking for.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223782/htaccess-forcing-a-slash-and-www).

Comment: only for the blog and everything else will redirect to squeeze page.

Answer (score 0):

The option to manually redirect the path "/blog" to "/blog/" by implementing a redirection rule. However, it's worth noting that if "/blog" corresponds to a physical folder, Apache automatically handles the trailing slash for you.

Comment: manually redirect path of https://ehsaas8171bisp.com.