# Wordpress installation in Joomla subdirectory

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, joomla

I've a Joomla 1.5.26 installation on the root of my hosting space. I would like to install a wordpress site in a subdirectory.

So I've edited the .htaccess file in the root adding these two lines immediately after RewriteEngine On:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdirectory/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

I've edited also the functions.php file adding these two line after php opening tag (obviously using my domain and subdirectory name):

```
update_option('siteurl', 'http://www.example.com/subdirectory');
update_option('home', 'http://www.example.com/subdirectory');
```

I've changed the "home" and "siteurl" field value in the table wp_options in the mysql database with "http://www.example.com/subdirectory".

When I try to access the subdirectory I get an HTTP 500 error.

Comment: This might be helpful - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9092124/how-to-redirect-blog-to-blog

Answer (score 0):

I dont think is there any direct access link available in joomla for any subdirectory.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Certainly I can access the subdirectory because I can access the static pages inside wordpress root (for example readme.html). I think the problem is with Wordpress htaccess or Wordpress configuration.